Elementary functions: Can an arithmetic operation be a composition?
The elementary functions are the functions of one complex variable that are generated by applying finite numbers of $\rm{exp}$, $\ln$ and/or unary or multiary $\mathbb{C}$-algebraic functions.
Let
$n\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}$,
$f_1,...,f_n$ non-constant elementary functions, not an identity function,
$x$ a real or complex variable.
Are there algebraically independent non-constant elementary functions $f$ and $g$ over a non-discrete domain so that
$$f(x)+g(x)=(f_n\circ\cdots\circ f_1)(x),$$
$$f(x)\cdot g(x)=(f_n\circ\cdots\circ f_1)(x)$$
or
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=(f_n\circ\cdots\circ f_1)(x)?$$
I can't think of any examples. So I assume the answer is no.
The background of the question is the elementary invertibility of the elementary functions on the left-hand sides of the equations.
I'm familiar with precalculus and the transformation rules of elementary algebra. But the answer can also be with higher mathematics, e.g. abstract algebra, complex analysis or topology if necessary.
